# Anaconda activate batch file character escaping doesn't work like windows command line

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm trying to set a secret key in my activate file for an anaconda environment on windows.  The secret key contains special characters that need to be escaped (eg `%` and `^`).  Let's say the secret key literal is `foobar%foo^bar%foo`. On the command line I can run:

```
SET SECRET_KEY=foobar^%foo^^^^bar^%foo
ECHO %SECRET_KEY%
```

And it returns `foobar%foo^bar%foo`

However in \etc\activate.d\env_vars.bat as described [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#windows) I have the same line `SET SECRET_KEY=foobar^%foo^^^^bar^%foo`, I activate the environment and run the `ECHO %SECRET_KEY%` command and I get `foobarfoo` returned.

Does anyone know how to escape the characters properly to get the correct string set in the environmental variable?

Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7, Conda 4.4.10

Answer (score 2):

In the command line, the % sign can be escaped by %%, the ^ character with ^^ and then enclosing the string in "" ensures there are no special characters un-escaped. So, for `foobar%foo^bar%foo`, the secret_key value should be escaped like:

```
set SECRET_KEY="foobar%%foo^^^^bar%%foo"
```

More on this [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the `%` sign should be escaped as `%%`.  However, your `set SECRET_KEY="foobar%%foo^^bar%%foo"` comes out as `"foobar%foobar%foo"` (note quotations are in the string).  I changed to `set SECRET_KEY=foobar%%foo^^^^bar%%foo` and it works.